# C++ collision issue

Tags: c++, collision, sfml, quadtree

I am testing collision between numerous moving squares in a quadtree.

When two square collides, I invert their velocity, like this:

```
    for (auto pair : collisionPairs)
    {
        auto& square1 = static_cast<Square&>(*(pair.first));
        auto& square2 = static_cast<Square&>(*(pair.second));

        square1.setVelocity(-square1.getVelocity());

        square2.setVelocity(-square2.getVelocity());

    }
```

The problem is, collision detection is not always during one frame.

Sometimes, they are collision between same squares more than one frame, because the squares have been intersecting to deep.

So squares overlap and they keep reversing their velocity infinitely, which results a 0 velocity ( -velocity + velocity = 0 )

How could I fix this ?

EDIT : I've discovered that the deep intersection issue was caused by my quadtree, I forgot to check collision with the objects of children trees.

Now it STILL happens but very rarely, like 1 in 100 collisions, before it was ~20 from 100 collisions

Comment: Maybe you should modify their position too, so that they do not overlap anymore before they start to move in their new direction.

Comment: UPDATE: see my edit please. (I'll accept one of the answers later because it seems that there are several possibilities to fix it.)

Comment: Please don't post links to code! Narrow it to the relevant parts and show it in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In addition to the pure collision detection I'd also check, whether the centers of the squares move towards each other or not and only revert their velocity in the first case. For me to provide an example you'd have to provide information about your implementation of the `Square` class.

Edit: Essentially the logic would look something like this:

```
if (collision detected) {
    if ( (square2.posx-square1.posx)* (square2.vx-square1.vx) < 0) {            
        // EDIT: exchange velocities of square1 and square2 in x direction
    }
    if ( (square2.posy-square1.posy)* (square2.vy-square1.vy) < 0) {             
        // EDIT: exchange velocities of square1 and square2 in y direction
    }
}
```

This is of course far from a realistic collision simulation, but if you just want to see whether your collision detection works correctly it should suffice. 
Btw. I'm assuming, that the rectangle edges are all oriented along the x and y axis.

Comment: "only revert their velocity in the first case" and in the second case ? Anyway I don't really want realistic collision , it was just for testing my quadtree, reversing is ok even if it's weird.

Comment: If they don't move towards each other, their velocity has already been reversed and ther is no need to reverse it again

Comment: Ah I see, I've misunderstood

Comment: This seems to be the simplest way but I am having trouble to know if the centers move toward each other, is there a simple formula to check this knowing the position and velocity of the two squares ?

Comment: See my edit. Sorry for not using your actual classes

Comment: Thanks for doing it for me (I am bad at logic),  works perfect

Answer (score 2):

You could give your `Square` class an additional `inCollision()` state or so, and check this additionally:

```
if(!square1.inCollision()) {
    square1.setVelocity(-square1.getVelocity());
    square1.setInCollision(true);
}

// Analogous code for square2
```

---

```
// Set inCollision state to false, when you build the collisionPairs
// Simplyfied pseudo code:
if(intersect(square1,square2) {
     // make_pair blah blah
}
else {
     square1.setInCollision(false);
     square2.setInCollision(false);
}
```

Comment: I think this might pose some problems if an object collides with more than one object at the same time.

Comment: @broncoAbierto That's why I wrote _Simplyfied pseudo code:_ there.

Comment: Even if it is simplified, the inCollision state would not suffice, I think. Each frame, once objectA is detected to be colliding with objectB, no more collisions will be detected for objectA. It would be necessary to store the state of each possible collision pair.